# Alternative to browsershots.org for taking screenshots on multiple browsers on different platforms?

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, javascript, mobile, screenshot

I'm working on a project where I have to test a javascript library's compatibility on mobile platforms in different browsers on the most recent versions of different mobile browsers. I have been long searching for a tool to do this on and when I came across http://browsershots.org it was exactly what I needed. The only problem is it does not have the most recent browser versions. From the looks of it the site hasn't been maintained since 2015.

Are there any alternatives similar to this:

- Can allow me to get screenshots of a page loaded on multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE, Opera) on different screen sizes
- Has the most recent stable browser versions available (eg. for Chrome v66 and v65)
- Is affordable or open source. I am a student and can not afford most of the paid testing suite licenses

I will need to use this for about a month for my current project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this manually, or create for example Appium script to do this for you on cloud device labs.

Crossbrowsertesting could be a fit for you, they have quite simple "test recorder and they support Visual Testing.

They all have free trials, so it could fit your short-term needs :)

```
TestDroid
Sauce labs
Perfecto Mobile
Kobiton
Amazon AWS Device farm
Xamarin Test Cloud
Experitest
pCloudy
BrowserStack
Crossbrowsertesting
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I actually ended up using TestingBot and paid for 1 month to do screenshot testing. I will look into the Appium scripts though now that I would like more experience with this :)

Comment: @Sithe oh, that's great to hear! I hope your project went well :) I'll check the TestingBot!

Answer (score 0):

For the screenshot testing on multiple browser on different platforms,you can use a free online website called Sizzy. On this website, you can check your website’s look and feel on a lot of iOS and Android devices.
In most of the software testing companies, for a short term requirement, tester generally use Browserstack as it contains the most recent stable browser versions but it will gives you a limited duration in free trail.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this chrome extension for taking screenshots https://www.lambdatest.com/chrome-extension
I use it frequently.

Comment: This does not answer the question, the question is about cross-browser screenshots, IE, Safari, Firefox and Chrome. While your answer is only a tool for a single browser.